# R function to calculate mean, sd or median but the comparison don't seem to work is there a better way to do this?

Tags: r, function

How do I evaluate x in if else statements if they are functions?

```
   library(dplyr)
    stat_mtcars <- function(x) {
      if (x == mean) {
        wht_stat <-  "Mean"
      } else if(x == sd) {
        wht_stat <- "sd"
      } else if(x == median) {
        wht_stat <- "Median" 
      }
      output <- mtcars %>% 
        summarise(wht_stat = x(mpg))
      output
    }
    
    stat_mtcars(mean)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything special, you can pass the function names directly and apply them.

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

stat_mtcars <- function(x) {
  fun <- deparse(substitute(x))
  mtcars %>% 
    summarise(!!paste0(fun, '_stat') := x(mpg))
}

stat_mtcars(mean)
#  mean_stat
#1  20.09062

#Check output
mtcars %>% 
  summarise(wht_stat = mean(mpg))
#  wht_stat
#1 20.09062

stat_mtcars(sd)
#   sd_stat
#1 6.026948
```

Comment: I would like wht_stat to state what measure I used though.

Comment: this is works thanks but would you mind explaining what !!paste0 does? I mean the !! in front and := what the colon mean?

Comment: To evaluate a variable on left hand side we use `!!` with `:=`. This is actually very broad topic, try searching for non-standard evaluation to know more.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `rlang` to assist:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)
stat_mtcars <- function(x) {
  output <- mtcars %>% 
    summarise({{x}} := x(mpg))
  output
}

stat_mtcars(mean)

##      mean
## 1 20.09062
```

And regarding the question, we can `deparse(substitute(x))` to use what was supplied to the function.

```r
is_mean = function(x) {
  x_sub = substitute(x)
  deparse(x_sub) == 'mean'
}
is_mean(mean)
#> [1] TRUE
is_mean(meany)
#> [1] FALSE
```